# Django вывод больших таблиц в шаблоне

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Я потихоньку учу Django и наткнулся на то,что вывод таблицы через цикл в шаблоне (если данных много) сильно увеличивает 
время загрузки страницы
Как можно решить эту проблему, кроме как с помощью pagination?
Буду благодарен за любые советы и подсказки.

models.py:

```
'class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000,null=True,default='Отсутствует')
author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
files = models.FileField(upload_to='catalog/books/')

def file_link(self):
    if self.file:
        return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.files.url,)
    else:
        return "No attachment"

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    """
    Возвращает линк на экземпляр книги
    """
    return reverse('books', args=[str(self.id)])

def get_by_author(self):
    """
    Возвращает все книги от автора книги, со страницы которой поступил
        запрос
    """
    return Book.objects.filter(author=self.author)

def get_by_genre(self):
    """
    Тоже самое что и выше, но по жанру
    """
    return Book.objects.filter(genre=self.genre)
    `
```

views.py:

```
    'from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from .models import Book, Author, Genre
    from django.views.generic.list import ListView

#Функция находит жанр с наибольшим количеством книг с помощью перебора
#возвращает название этого жанра и количество книг
   def genreCheck(num_genres):
    flag=0
    flagId=0
    for i in range(1,num_genres):
        if Book.objects.filter(genre=Genre.objects.get(id=i)).count()>flag:
            flag=Book.objects.filter(genre=Genre.objects.get(id=i)).count()
            flagId=i
    return Genre.objects.get(id=flagId).name,flag

    def index(request):
    """
    Функция отображения для домашней страницы сайта.
    """
    # Получаем количество книг,авторов,жанров
    num_books=Book.objects.count()

    num_authors=Author.objects.count()  

    num_genres=Genre.objects.count()
    #Запрашиваем из бд информацию по последней добавленой книги 
    # и записываем полученный обьект в переменную
    last_book=Book.objects.get(id=num_books)

    #Получаем название самого популярного жанра и количество книг в нём
    popularGenreName,popularGenreCount=genreCheck(num_genres)
    #Получаем из бд всеги книги из самого популярного жанра
    # название последней сохраняем
    popularGenreBook=Book.objects.filter(genre=Genre.objects.get(name=popularGenreName))[popularGenreCount-1].title

    Books=Book.objects.all()

    # Отрисовка HTML-шаблона index.html с данными внутри 
    # переменной контекста context
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        context={'num_books':num_books,'num_authors':num_authors,
    'num_genres':num_genres,'last_book':last_book,'popularGenreName':popularGenreName,'popularGenreCount':popularGenreCount,
             'popularGenreBook':popularGenreBook,'Books':reversed(Books),
             }
    )'
```

Вывожу с помощью цикла:

```
<table>
       <tr >
        <td ><p><strong>Название:</strong></p></td>
         <td ><p><strong>Жанр</strong></p></td>
        <td ><p><strong>Автор</strong></p></td>
        <td><p><strong>Ознакомится</strong></p></td>
        </tr>   
      {% for book in Books %}
      <tr >
         <td style='width:25%'>
            <p><a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}"style='text-size:8px'>{{ book.title }}</a></p>
         </td>
         <td >{{ book.genre }}</td>
         <td >{{ book.author }}</td>
         <td><a href='{{ book.files }}'style='left:6px'>Скачать</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </table>
```

Comment: Если данных действительно много, то для просмотра в реальных проектах используется пагинация. сортировка и поиск выполняются на стороне сервера. С пагинацией возвращается обычно не более 100-200 записей. Это хорошая и необходимая практика

Answer (score 0):

помимо того что можно припилить кэширование в функции вида, можно кэшировать отдельные блоки в шаблоне https://djbook.ru/rel1.5/topics/cache.html .

Конечно это не спасет от длительного выполнения первого запроса еще без кеша, но на этот счет можно вынести различные резалтсеты в шаблоне по разным AJAX-видам - и собрать все уже у клиента несколькими запросами.